# Compilation error while installing Moveit from source

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I was trying to do source based installation of recently released "Moveit". When the installation reached 61% I am getting the following error:

```
[ 60%] Building CXX object moveit_ros/planning/trajectory_execution_manager/CMakeFiles/test_controller_manager.dir/test/test_app.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/karthik/groovy_workspace/moveit/devel/lib/libtest_controller_manager_plugin.so
/home/karthik/groovy_workspace/moveit/src/moveit_ros/planning/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp: In member function ‘void planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor::excludeRobotLinksFromOctree()’:
/home/karthik/groovy_workspace/moveit/src/moveit_ros/planning/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp:533:10: error: ‘class shapes::Mesh’ has no member named ‘mergeVertices’
[ 60%] Built target test_controller_manager_plugin
Linking CXX executable /home/karthik/groovy_workspace/moveit/devel/lib/moveit_ros_planning/test_controller_manager
[ 60%] Built target test_controller_manager
make[2]: *** [moveit_ros/planning/planning_scene_monitor/CMakeFiles/moveit_planning_scene_monitor.dir/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [moveit_ros/planning/planning_scene_monitor/CMakeFiles/moveit_planning_scene_monitor.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

I tried uninstalling ROS,reinstalled it again without debian based moveit and it gives the same issue. Please help me on this.
I am working on
*ROS-GROOVY
*Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62029/compilation-error-while-installing-moveit-from-source/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-10-09**:
What version of moveit are you using? It's likely that recent versions of moveit are not fully backwards compatible with Groovy.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-20**:
Yes, it is not compatible for previous versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Current moveit is not compatible to previous versions of ROS. So, maybe that's the reason. Also, current version of moveit is also not compatible to ROS-Kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) with karma: 167 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-08**:
Just a comment on the "not compatible to ROS-Kinetic": that's actually not entirely accurate. A release of MoveIt for Kinetic is in the works, and can already be built from sources. See the [instructions](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/) on the website. If something doesn't work, report it.